# Please how do i print pairs of X and t in PYTHON?

Tags: python-2.7

Please how do i print pairs of X and t in PYTHON?

X = [8, 10, 1]

t = [10, 8, 1]

#### Something like

[[8, 10], [10, 8], [1,1]]

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you don't insist on getting a list of lists) you can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
list(zip(X,t))
```

Result:

```
[(8, 10), (10, 8), (1, 1)]
```